# How to debug rsync's --link-dest option?

Tags: rsync, debugging

Is there some way to make `rsync` report **why** it decided to make a new copy of a file, instead of hard-linking it? (E.g. because of timestamp, or detected a change in content... etc.)

(I'm creating incremental backups but some files which should not have been changed for long time, are still getting copied over instead of hard-linked.)

**Related, but does not solve my problem:** [rsync --link-dest not linking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450394)

In that question,  **all** files are being copied instead of linked, whereas in my case only **some** files are being copied (so I guess the syntax of the command is correct).

For reference, **the command I'm using** is:

```
rsync -av -delete --link-dest=/path/to/previous/backup/ /path/to/source/ /path/to/new/backup/
```

(Note the slashes at the end!)

Comment: Use `-i` (`--itemize-changes`) in place of `-v` (`--verbose`).  It will give you more information about why a file is being copied. If that solves your issue, I may write it up as a proper answer later (if nobody else does first).

Comment: Thanks, that was it indeed.
For the records, I got this result: `cf.....g...`, which, if I understand correctly, means that checksum and group are different. The checksum did not change, though (I tried md5sum), but the groups were indeed not the same.

Comment: No, initial `c` just means that this update is a "change". (The first character is the "update type".  Had it been a transfer then it would have had `>` or `<` instead).  What's happening for that  particular file is that the group is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `--itemize-changes` (or `-i`) in place of `-v` gives slightly more information about the reason something happens to the files that you run `rsync` on.

For example, if a file has had its group ownership changed but nothing else, you may see something like `cf.....g...` for that file.  The initial character is the "update type" and a `c` simply means "change" (i.e. not a transfer of file data).  The following `f` is the file type ("regular file").  The `g` further along the string means that the group is different between the source and the target.

This is all described in the `rsync` manual. Look for the longer description of the `--itemize-changes` option.

When the meta data of a file changes, it can no longer be created as a hard link of an pre-existing copy of the same file with `--link-dest`. The meta data can't be different for hard links of the same file.